# Google Authentication in Razor Pages (Blazor Server Project)

Tags: .net, razor, google-oauth

I'm trying to implement **Google Authentication** in my **Blazor Server Web Application**. In my app I use the same system as I scaffolded security (UserManager and SignInManager) but I use custom razor pages.
I would like to retrive the google info from the account chosen and then create a user in my db with all the informations.
I followed this tutorial https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/830958/how-to-implement-google-authetication-in-blazor-se but the response method always doesn't pass the if statement because the user object is null...
Please can someone suggest something to look for debugging my problem?

Here is my program.cs and my razor pages:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Aggiunge le configurazioni per il database e l'autenticazione legata al database.
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("StatTrade");
builder.Services.AddDbContext<StatTradeDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
builder.Services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>(options =>
{
    options.Password.RequireDigit = false;
    options.Password.RequiredLength = 5;
    options.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
    options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
    options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
    options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = false;
})
    .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<StatTradeDbContext>();

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = GoogleDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
    .AddCookie()
    .AddGoogle(GoogleDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, opt =>
    {
        opt.ClientId = builder.Configuration["Google:Id"];
        opt.ClientSecret = builder.Configuration["Google:Secret"];
        opt.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("urn:google:picture", "picture", "url");

    });

builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
builder.Services.AddScoped<HttpContextAccessor>();
builder.Services.AddHttpClient();
builder.Services.AddScoped<HttpClient>();


// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor();

// Aggiutna dipendenza per fontawesome.
builder.Services
    .AddBlazorise()
    .AddBootstrap5Providers()
    .AddFontAwesomeIcons();

AddBlazorise(builder.Services);



var app = builder.Build();










// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseCookiePolicy();
app.UseRouting();


// Aggiunge il sistema di autenticazione standard di Microsoft alla mia Web App.
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();




app.MapBlazorHub();
app.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
app.MapRazorPages();

app.Run();


void AddBlazorise(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services
        .AddBlazorise();
    services
        .AddBootstrap5Providers()
        .AddFontAwesomeIcons();
}
```

and my razor page:

```
namespace BlazorGmail.Pages.Identity
{
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public class LoginModel : PageModel
    {
       
        public IActionResult OnGetAsync(string returnUrl = null)
        {
            // Request a redirect to the external login provider.
            var authenticationProperties = new AuthenticationProperties
            {
                RedirectUri = Url.Page("./GoogleLogin",
                pageHandler: "Callback",
                values: new { returnUrl }),

            };
            return new ChallengeResult(GoogleDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, authenticationProperties);
        }
        public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetCallbackAsync(
            string returnUrl = null, string remoteError = null)
        {
            // Get the information about the user from the external login provider
            var GoogleUser = this.User.Identities.FirstOrDefault();
            if (GoogleUser.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                var authProperties = new AuthenticationProperties
                {
                    IsPersistent = true,
                    RedirectUri = this.Request.Host.Value
                };
                await HttpContext.SignInAsync(
                CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
                new ClaimsPrincipal(GoogleUser),
                authProperties);
            }
            return LocalRedirect("/");


            
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
var GoogleUser = HttpContext.User;
```

instead of

```
var GoogleUser = this.User.Identities.FirstOrDefault();
```